# Dockerfile cannot find copied folder

Tags: docker

This is quite strange.

I have a structure like this

```
app/
CLI/
someOtherFolder/
  thingIwantToRun.py
tests.Dockerfile
Dockerfile
README.md
gunicorn.conf
```

This is what my `Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /.requirements.txt
# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /.requirements.txt
COPY gunicorn.conf /gunicorn.conf

COPY . /app



EXPOSE 8000


RUN ls

ENV FLASK_ENV=development

CMD ["python ./someOtherFolder/thingIwantToRun.py"]
```

This gives me this error when I start the container -

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls ./someOtherFolder\": stat ls ./someOtherFolder: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

When I change the `CMD` command into something else which doesn't fail and I jump into the container I see that my folder is indeed there.

When I add a `RUN ls` into my Dockerfile, I can still see my folder.

If it exists, why can't I run it?

UPDATE -

If I move `thingIWantToRun.py` into the top level folder and change my Docker `CMD` to

`CMD [python thingIWantToRun.py]`

I see the same issue. However, I can ssh into the container and verify that the file is there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you are running the `CMD` command. It is something like this:

```
CMD ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
```

ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

In that sense actual command should be

```
CMD ["python", "./someOtherFolder/thingIwantToRun.py"]
```

Docker tries to find the `executable` part (first item of the array) and run it, and passes rest of the array items (`param1, param2`) to it. If you look closer to the error is prints

```
... process caused "exec: \"ls ./someOtherFolder\": stat ls ./someOtherFolder: no such file or directory"
```

It says that `ls ./someOtherFolder` is not a file or directory and it can't `exec` it! Which is the first item of the array, the executable!
Here `ls` should be first item and `./someOtherFolder` should be second item of array for `CMD` command.

Comment: I tried this and I got this error

python: can't open file './someOtherFolder/thingIwantToRun.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @praks5432 well that means `CMD` command can run python. Now just make sure you have right folder structure, change the file path `./someOtherFolder/thingIwantToRun.py` as needed and it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CMD command something like this:

```
CMD ["python", "./someOtherFolder/thingIwantToRun.py"]
```